# Как извлечь данные из тэга xml?

Tags: java, xml

Имеется такой xml файл: как быстро и просто извлечь в String значение поля value в указанном тэге (production:operationBO). Заранее благодарю!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мое решение (не работает):

```
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        String data =
                xPath.evaluate(
                        "//production:operationBO[@key='value']",
                        new InputSource(fileReader)
                );
        System.out.println(data);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, прикладывайте текствую информацию в виде текста, а не скриншотом, чтобы ее можно было копировать и чтобы работал поиск. Кроме этого, укажите в вопросе, какую реализацию XPath вы используете в своем коде. Попробуйте изменить xpath-выражение на `//production:operationBO/value`

Comment: Нужно обязательно учитывать пространства имён (как раз то, что вы замазали). `production` - это префикс неймспейса, а не часть имени тэга.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш XML имеет пространство имен (namespace). Следует позаботиться об этом.

Пожалуйста, смотрите ниже, как.

**Java**

```
NamespaceContext ctx = new NamespaceContext() {
    public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
        return prefix.equals("production") ? "whatever-is-hidden" : null; 
    }
    public Iterator getPrefixes(String val) {
        return null;
    }
    public String getPrefix(String uri) {
        return null;
    }
};

XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
xpath.setNamespaceContext(ctx);

String data = xPath.evaluate("//production:operationBO/value/text()",
                        new InputSource(fileReader)
                );
System.out.println(data);
```